# JQuery shaking effect with some tilt/rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an effect where on button click, the div would shake left and right and tilt about 10deg each way so it looks like a natural motion when shaking an object with two hands. I am able to create the left and right shaking effect but can't seem to tie it in with rotation. I also need this to work in IE8, so css3 is not an option. I am using JQuery UI and .rotate() but if there is a better way please let me know. I need this to shake about 3-4 times on button click.

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="globe-main" id="globe">
    <div class="content"></div><!-- end .content -->
</div><!-- end .globe-main -->
    </div><!-- end .container -->

    <script>

var times = 4;
var loop = setInterval(rota, 300);

function rota() {
    times--;
    if(times === 0){clearInterval(loop);}
    $(".globe-main").rotate({animateTo:10, duration: 500, });
    //$(".globe-main").effect("shake", { times:3, distance:30 }, 800);

}
rota(); 

    </script>
```

Here is what I have so far [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J2ySt/)

Thank you

UPDATE

Here is the updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J2ySt/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has no method called `rotate`. This is probably where the problem lies.

**Edit**

Based on your comments, you could create your own queue I guess...

```
rotationAnimationQueue = {
   queue: [],
   addAnimation: function( $jQueryObject, params ) {
      // add animation to the queue
      this.queue.push( {
         $jQueryObject: $jQueryObject,
         params: params
      } );
      // if only animation in queue, begin processing
      if ( this.queue.length === 1 ) this.processQueue();
   },
   processQueue: function() {
      var self = this;
      var animation = this.queue[ 0 ];
      animation.params.callback = function() {
         self.queue.shift();
         if ( self.queue.length > 0 ) self.processQueue();
      };
      animation.$jQueryObject.rotate( animation.params );
   }
};
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/UnyYh/1/

You may want to modify the queue code so that it keeps track of one queue per jQuery object. This way if needed you could have shake animations happening on multiple objects at the same time instead of always doing the animations in sequence.

Comment: @markopfc So include that plugin so the fiddle works, you do it in the **Add Resources** sidebar item.

Comment: thank you for the tip, here is the updated fiddle with what I have http://jsfiddle.net/J2ySt/2/

Comment: @markopfc looks like they have not tested this plugin on safari. what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using FF but I need this to shake and tilt left and right 3-4 times, I can get the animateTo but I want it to animate from 0 to -10 to 10 about 3-4 times

Comment: @markopfc I see. The problem with that is, whoever built this plugin, did create it to the same standards as other jQuery animations. Basically animations do not get queued. If you did three animation in a row in your code, the plugin would simply skip to the last one instead of queueing and performing sequentially. If it had something like a callback parameter, you could string them together yourself, but it doesn't have that either. You may want to look for a better plug in.

Comment: It does have a callback if you look here, second code on example 3 http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples Do you have any better idea of how I can accomplish this? or another plugin? thank you

Comment: @markopfc edited answer to show you what I might do if forced to use this plugin. There may be another plugin that uses jQuery's native animation queue in which case you wouldn't have to do any of this. You would just be able to call all the animations in a row, and they would automatically sequence themselves to play in order.

Comment: this works great, it is the solution to my troubles! is there a way I can call this on button click <a id="button">button</a>? I can wrap it in $('#button').click(function {}); ?

Comment: @markopfc don't wrap the whole object definition within the click handler, otherwise it will recreate this whole object every time the link is clicked, but do wrap the code that activates the object's addAnimation() method within your click handler.

Comment: dqhendricks I'm having trouble finding exactly when I should input the click handler.

Comment: @dqhendricks to follow up, I did manage to add the click handler shortly after my last post. Thank you for your script/help, it works great and does what I was looking for. Thanks again.